# Allow Form Controls to affect a Locked Cell

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel spread sheet that has form controls in place so that only the numbers 0 through 4 can be entered into a cell. These form controls are two arrows, one pointing up to increase the value and one pointing down to decrease the value. The affected cell is set to 0 by default and have the minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 4. However, if I lock the cell, so that a user cannot manually enter a number, the form controls no longer work. Is there any way to prevent a user from manually typing in a number, but still allow the form controls to limit only numbers between 0-4?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this on my own. Navigate to the Data Ribbon, then select Data Validation. Allow a whole number and set the data between a minimum of "0" and a Maximum of "4" Then, set an error alert stating the business rule as to why the value can only be between 0 and 4. The user will be unable to navigate off of the cell without changing the value between it's minimum and maximum values.